# Need help to update values in ACF via WP API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm trying to update an item particularly with the "rows" feature in WordPress ACF plugin via PHP using Wordpress API.

The value I'm looking to change is "Monday"

Here's the json from the endpoint:

```
{
    "id": 765,
    "acf": {
        "contact": "2150",
        "sched": [
            {
                "field_611218a978d03": "Monday",
                "field_6112197d78d04": "00:00:00",
                "field_6112199f78d05": "17:00:00"
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

I can change the value of "2150" to "2151" with the following:

```
'body' => array(
        'acf' => array (
            'contact' => "2151",
        ),
    )
```

But I can't change the value of "Monday", I've already tried the following:

```
'body' => array(
        'acf' => array (
            'sched' => array ( array ( "field_611218a978d03" => "Tuesday")
        )
    )
```

As well as:

```
'body' => array(
        'acf' => array (
            'sched' => array ( 
                  [0] => array( "field_611218a978d03" => "Tuesday")
        )
    )
)
```

I've been searching and there seems to be no answer pertaining to this specific problem. I've been stumped for days now. Any help would sincerely be appreciated!

Edit:
To answer CBroe this is the code I'm working with:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/person/765', array(    
    'headers' => array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:pass' )),
    'body' => array(
        'acf' => array (
            'contact' => '2150',
            'sched' => array ( array ( "field_611218a978d03" => "Tuesday")
        ),
    )
    ));

    $body = json_decode( $api_response['body'],true);
```

Comment: What endpoint? What actual functions are you calling?

Comment: @CBroe I've placed the whole code at the bottom, please be patient with me as I try to answer your questions